# How to put a file along with a custom class in a POST Rest call?

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest, nlog

I've been scraping my head for a while, i just can't figure out on how to do this with NLogger(Net4.7.5)

The intention of this HttpPost request is that its supposed to send a .stl file together with a custom class in a WebRequest, ultimately i want something like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyQk0.png).

In net6.0, atleast inside a web api as far as i'm aware of you could return using FileContentResult ControllerBase.File() pretty easily. But i haven't found an alternative to it in net4.7.5.

This is as far as i got using net4.7.5 with NLogger

```
private static bool PingServer(string server, object seDocument)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp($"http://{server}//stl");
    webRequest.Timeout = 5000; //Default is 100.000 (100 seconds)...
    webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;


    Byte[] stlFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($@"{listTempFiles[0]}");
    String base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(stlFile);

    //Note to future me, this doesn't need to be jsonified
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(seDocument);
    byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

    switch (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(listTempFiles[0]))
    {
        case ".stl":
        case ".STL":
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/sla";
            break;

        case ".jt":
        case ".JT":
            webRequest.ContentType = ".";
            break;

        default:
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            break;
    }
    webRequest.ContentLength = b.Length;

    using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response;
    try
    {
        response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info(e.Message);
        return false;
    }

    if (response != null)
    {
        LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
        .Info($"'{server}' responded with status '{response.StatusCode.ToString()}'");
    }

    return response == null || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
```

I did something similar in net6.0 using a WebApi with HttpGet

```
[HttpGet("{mainpath}/{true}")]
public List<MendixFile> GetAll(string mainpath)
{
  List<MendixFile> mendixFiles = new List<MendixFile>();

  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(mainpath, "*", searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories);
  foreach (string file in files)
    {
       Byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($@"{file}");
       string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
       string name= Path.GetFileName(file);
       MendixFile mendixFile = new MendixFile(path, name, b);
       File(b, "image/jpg");
       mendixFiles.Add(mendixFile);
    }
    return mendixFiles;
}
```

Note: I can't switch to other frameworks as net4.7.5 has some mandatory libraries i can only use within net4.7.5.

Additional note: listTempFiles[0] is always C:/Temp/Part.stl by default

Comment: Do you control the server side code that is handling this POST request? You could use a custom header if the json is small, with HttpWebRequest.Headers.Add(string, string);

Comment: Looks like I was overthinking the problem, I just had to let the server decode the base64String into a fileformat instead of sending a request directly with custom attached attribute to it. Apologies for the inconvenience!